# "Array to Hash" transform in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, transform

I need to transform `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`  to `{:a => {:b => {:c => "d" }}}` ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd be a little careful: how would you know that it should be converted to `{:a => {:b => {:c => "d" }}}` rather than `{:a => :b, :c => :d}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like it:

```
class Array
  def to_weird_hash
    length == 1 ? first : { first.to_sym => last(length - 1).to_weird_hash }
  end
end

["a", "b", "c", "d"].to_weird_hash
```

What do you think?

Comment: What version of ruby is this valid for?

Comment: OK. I'm getting undefined method `from` in both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2

Comment: I'm doing it now with irb and it's not working, before I did it in script/console. Apparently the method Array#from doesn't exist... :S

Comment: Sounds like it is a ROR Monkeypatch.

Answer (score 4):

funny

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > ["a", "b", "c", "d"].reverse.inject{|hash,item| {item.to_sym => hash}}
 => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"d"}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do it for exactly 4 elements, it's easy enought to just write it out (and quite readable too)

```
>> A=["a", "b", "c", "d"]
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>> {A[0].to_sym => {A[1].to_sym => {A[2].to_sym => A[3]}}}
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"d"}}}
```

Otherwise, this will work for variable length arrays

```
>> ["a", "b", "c", "d"].reverse.inject(){|a,e|{e.to_sym => a}}
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"d"}}}
>> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"].reverse.inject(){|a,e|{e.to_sym => a}}
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>{:e=>"f"}}}}}
```

Comment: I need it with more than one element.

Comment: @retro, not sure what you mean by more than one element. I added a way to do it with variable length arrays

Comment: I meant I have more than one element in input array. Also nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help on IRC.

```
x = {}; a[0..-3].inject(x) { |h,k| h[k.to_sym] = {} }[a[-2].to_sym] = a[-1]; x
```

Second way with recursive (better)

```
def nest(a)
  if a.size == 2
    { a[0] => a[1] }
  else
    { a[0] => nest(a[1..-1]) }
  end
end
```